# Alchemy pending transactions indefinetly

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, polygon, alchemy

I changed literally nothing and the transactions for contract creations don't go through anymore.

I'm using `hardhat` and deploying on `mumbai`. I have set `blockGasLimit: 999999999999999,`.

Any ideas why this happens? MEGA annoying...

EDIT: 3hrs later they all went through after all. Is there any special reason maybe?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue but on Goerli